# Rails Mailer does not send emails. Smtp settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, ruby-on-rails-5, mailer

### UPDATE:

Problem was so silly that it shouldn't even be on StackExchange. 
Adress had to be written Address...

### But now I get it - :sendmail was working fine, since it created its own server. But, what is strange, that letters sent via :sendmail went to junk box, while now, after I figured out that silly mistake and fixed app to use :smtp directly, all letters comes to normal Inbox even dough I fixed error in word address - it probably means that by using :sendmail, :smtp ignores outgoing server and uses its own, from localhost...

Problems on delivering email on my very first Rails 5 app (Agile Web Development with Rails 5)

Models:

```
Product
LineItem
Cart
Order
```

Users adds one Product or more to Cart as a LineItem. Hits checkout, fills his email and confirms order. At this point email should be delivered to his email adress, but it is not happening.

orders_controller.rb (`create` action):

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        OrderMailer.received(@order).deliver_later
        format.html { redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

order_mailer.rb (`received` method - this should send that email):

```
  def received(order)
    @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Order confirmation'
  end
```

development.rb:

```
Depot::Application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    adress:         "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:           587,
    domain:         "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name:      "my-gmail-account",
    password:       "my-gmail-password",
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

From the log I assume it is something wrong with routing..?:

```
  Rendering /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered collection of /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [34 times] (9.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendering /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (93.8ms)
```

I tried restarting Webrick on my Mac (Ctrl + C) and changed Gmail email settings to allow less secure apps using it. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Use `deliver` instead of `deliver_later` , see what's happening next ?

Comment: then i get  `Errno::ECONNREFUSED in OrdersController#create
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 587`

Comment: please use .deliver_now for trigger mail from rails 5

Comment: still get the same error as above...

Comment: if possible just try to add another mail client smtp setting like spark post, some times gmail account make issue for trigger mail from rails application

Comment: I have added an answer for my problem bellow. Still it didnt completely fixed my problem. Hope to get further help. thx

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `development.rb` :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: already tried that. Also tried using `authentication: "login"`

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius Inplace of port: 587, did you try 25 or 465 ?

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius try from your terminal `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`, you should get result like `Trying 2404:6800:4003:c00::6c...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP y189sm17798621pfy.34 - gsmtp`

If you don't see such a result, then you can try telnet with other ports like 25 or 465. If none of the ports are allowing to getting connected to gmail smtp server, then there is something wrong in your system. If it works, then something is blocking at gmail server.

Comment: hm i get exact result as you wrote here

Comment: oh and thanks for great info. Sad, that it didnt answered my question

Answer (score 1):

Please find below solution.

add default url option for action mailer inside you env file.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'YOUR HOST NAME', port: PORT OF YOUR SERVER }
```

Please use .deliver_now for quick action of action mailer.

Comment: Please check by configuring other mail client smtp setting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [mailcatcher gem](https://mailcatcher.me/) for comfortable development emails debugging.